# How to return a list of files uploaded in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where i want to return a list of files uploaded.
I use

```
ui.R : fileInput("files", "Choose CSV processed files", multiple = "TRUE",
                                accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv','.cel'))
```

and

```
server.R :  list <- list.files(path = "input$files[['datapath]]", pattern =".cel")
```

or

```
list <- list.files(input$files[['datapath']])
```

but it returns `character(0)`. May i know Y .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `[['datapath']]` give you the temporary data path to upload the files in shiny. 
You can try `list <- input$files[['name']]` to get the list of files uploaded in shiny.

Comment: OMG.. This small mistake . Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wrap list.files in `reactive()` that's the way that Shiny knows to monitor and update the `input$` value based on the file input. If you're doing something more specific any of the render* functions will do the same thing.

`server.R :  list <- reactive(
list.files(path = "input$files[['datapath]]", pattern =".cel")
)`

Comment: Not working. I tried different ways, like `reactive()`,`observe()`